# jQuery - how to find an element with square brackets in its ID attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

I'm working with jQuery and I have this element:

```
<input class="css-checkbox" id="services[3492][selected]" name="services[3492][selected]" type="checkbox" value=" 1">
```

When I try to get that item in my console through its ID — `services[3492][selected]` — I get an empty response: `[]`.

Code:

```
$('#services[3490][selected]') // Not working
$('[id*="services[3490][selected]"') // Working
```

I think it's because the `[` characters. Maybe I need to sanitize, or use some escape characters or unicode transformation.

Comment: `$('[id*="services[3490][selected]"')`  is missing a closing `]` after the `"`. is that accurate, and working even so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the metacharacters( such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~` ) in jquery selector using `\\`.

```
$('#services\\[3490\\]\\[selected\\]')
```

---

From [jQuery selecctors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) docs :

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS specification contains the [complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on [CSS character escape sequences for identifiers](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).

Answer (score 4):

Per jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/),

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

To use brackets in the first example, I believe your selector would need to be:

`$('#services\\[3490\\]\\[selected\\]')`

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the square brackets in the `id` selector so they are not interpreted as attribute selectors:

```
$('#services\\[3490\\]\\[selected\\]')
```